# Property 'indx' does not exist on type

Tags: angular, angular5

I have been working on Angular 5 project and I was trying run `npm build -prod` with AOT as defult one. After compiling error pop up as

```
Property 'indx' does not exist on type 'EntryComponent'
```

Can any on point out the mistake. Or it some thing else.

```
<div *ngFor="let form of getEntryGroupItemsControl(); let indx = index; trackBy: indx">
```

Comment: Ensure that your are using `trackBy` properly: [*ngFor with trackBy](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#ngfor-with-trackby)

Comment: Yes I am using __trackBy__ property

Comment: Error is not in that html, instead, i guess, you are using `indx` outside of that `div`

Comment: No, error message  is pointing this line only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is the wrong syntax. `trackBy` should point to a function, not to an index from the loop. So it should by something like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let form of getEntryGroupItemsControl(); let indx = index; trackBy: trackByFn">
```

And in TS file for example:

```
trackByFn(index, item) { 
  return item.id; 
}
```

For reference see:
1) https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf
2) https://angular.io/api/core/TrackByFunction

And here`s an example from official Angular tutorial: https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#ngfor-with-trackby

Comment: I found this question because I was using "let i = index;trackBy:trackByIndex;" Which worked using ng serve and ng build, but it threw an error "Property 'trackByIndex' does not exist on type" using ng build --prod.  This answer fixed my issue as well. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I fixed it using "index as i".

https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf